# Can moderators delete comments without notifying the user and without citing valid reasons?

Tags: support, moderators, comments

My comments which were posted under [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10630/if-a-hindu-cant-kill-animals-how-do-they-get-tiger-carpets) question were deleted.

Question-Is it normal for site moderators to delete any comment without showing any reasons for the deletion?

Also,isn't the concerned user supposed to get a notification that his comment has been deleted?

Comment: Comments are never supposed to be permanent, chatty/offensive/obsolete comments can be deleted without notification.

Comment: On the side note your comments did attracted flags too for being rude and offensive. I don't find them that offensive but were of no use and not helping the question much but becoming more of an argument.

Comment: @Rickross Topic related comments are important. Those comments will never be deleted.

Comment: Inorder to keep the site clean and on topic, we do keep regular checks on posts farming many comments, if the discussion is done, we clean them up, if the discussion is extensive, we move them to a chat room, if your comments are adding valuable content to the post we keep it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/187039) to [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/187039)</sup>

### When should comments be deleted?

Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. **You should not expect them to be around forever**: Once a clarification has been made, an edit added to the post to include new information, or the issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it is subject to deletion. In reality, many obsolete or chatty comments remain untouched due to the high volume of comments posted, but this does not mean that they can't or shouldn't be deleted in the future.

### Who can delete comments?

A user may delete one of his own comments by clicking on the (x) icon that appears to the right of the comment's timestamp when the comment is moused over. A user can delete only one comment every five seconds.

**Comments that are flagged by multiple users are deleted automatically.** The number of flags needed is based on the comment's score. It currently takes "3 + (Score / 3)" flags to delete a comment.

**Moderators can delete any comment, or purge all comments from a post.**

Comment: Nice answer. I was not aware of 3 flag methodology. Are you sure? What if the flags are different from each others?

Comment: @iammilind Not sure. I just copied parts of the answer from Meta.SE. But you can pick any comment and we could try flagging :) Looks like some fellas [went to great lengths](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138168/reduce-the-threshold-for-comment-deletion-with-flags?lq=1#comment388189_138168) to figure out the logic.

Comment: Good idea. So let's take the comment in [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10152/1049), which states "@iammilind: Thanks :)". Even though it is acknowledging in nice way, usually I find such comments or 1 liners as waste of resources; instead one should upvote it. I have flagged it as "not constructive", you may flag it "too chatty" and someone else can as "obsolete". Btw, once you do that, simply upvote this comment. I will assume it to be done. Lets follow what we preach. :)

Comment: @iammilind I just flagged it. Not sure what happened there. I believe one of the moderators caught it and deleted before auto-delete could do its magic :)

Comment: Now i see the reason for that flag:D