# Guidelines for when to use "Chat" instead of "Comment"

Tags: discussion, faq, comments, chat

In SE, we have 4 forms of right to express self. They are listed below in order of importance:

1. Question
2. Answer
3. Comment
4. Chat

"Question" is the most important, because everything revolves around it. "Answer" tries to fulfill the query. "Comment" is a supporting instrument, while "Chat" is a casual tool.

In Hinduism.SE, I often see that people miss to see the difference between the last 2. Many users unknowingly tend to put 1 liner consecutive comments instead of combining them into single. Shouldn't we optimally utilize the limit of 600 characters provided by it?
It's easy to miss some good comments (sometimes as good as answer), because there are too many of 'not so useful' ones as well.

Moreover, we should also be careful while replying via comments to each other, when it tends to loose the relevance. **Comments are for inputs and not debates**. One doesn't win a discussion/debate, if he/she puts the last comment. It sometimes simply means that the other person doesn't find it useful to say anything further.
 We always can [create a chatroom](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/464/1049) or use an existing one.

Moderators are helpful in this regard to delete the chatty/obsolete/non-constructive comments most of the time. The chances reduces by 50%, if I flag a moderator comment though :-).
Should there be a guideline for "How to/Where to/When to" comment?

[Return to FAQ index](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR** -
Comments should only be used if they give any constructive input to the post (Q&A) and don't turn out to be a long/open ended debate/discussion.
There is nothing wrong if there is a prolonged conversation with a fellow user, however in such case, it's better to use Chats, as they are meant to serve such purposes and even to talk on off topic stuffs as well.

---

The whole guideline are present in [privileges](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/) section of our site. But to concentrate on what explicitly asked here, lets start with comments:

When should I comment?
You should submit a comment if you want to:

> **When should I comment?**
>
> - Request **clarification** from the author;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the
>     question has been updated). [*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

So its quite clear from this three points. First, comments are fro clarification, I do have tendency to use the comments for the first reason more. Rather then flagging, downvoting and close voting straight its better to ask the questioner for clarification in case of doubt until its non salvageable. Second is constructive criticism, "constructive" is important part of it and we should not forget [be nice](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy too. Third but not the last is minor or transient information, to add something related in comment.

But its better not to drag the comments for infinite discussions, it will uncomfortable for a new visitor to see 100s of message under a single question, longer discussions should be moved to chat. And chat also give you freedom to discuss unrelated stuff too. But under a question, they might get removed.

Now the second part of the question is

> **When shouldn't I comment?**
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;
> - Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an
>     existing one);
> - Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward;
> - Criticisms which do not add anything constructive ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or up-vote
>     a better answer if appropriate);
> - Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use chat instead;
> - Discussion of community behavior or site policies; please use meta instead.

First if you are suggesting an edit, why didn't go forward and do it? That's what the edit privilege is for. Second point is not to give alternate answer in comments, multiple answer can't be a bad idea until you are copy pasting from existing one. No need to talk on third point, "+1" comments are useless and should be removed, if you want to +1, then upvote, give bounties, accept answer if its your question. Next point is about a non constructive comments, no need to provide "same as above comment". Next is controversial topic, controversial topic= lots of lots of comments and it should be done in chat. But remember to be civil while discussing them , don't attract flags and don't make people to raise eyebrow. Last but not the least "community behavior or site policies" and for that meta is the right place not comments. You can refer it in comment like "refer respective meta" with links but no need to discuss them in main site.

For other details refer privilege or help center section or to [A guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments)

On the bottom-line, remember that comments are not permanent and they can be deleted. [Refer here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/476/76) for related discussion.

---

Lets talk about [third place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_place) now. Chat in stack exchange is also like third place, first is you main site, second meta and then come chat.

It also have a [guideline](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) to be followed. But to summarize it, chat is less strict then other two places and we can have fun in chat too. Mods also can be seen in the our [main chat-room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) and you guys can join us and we don't bite.

Chat-room also fall under be nice policy and we should respect our fellow user there too. We can discuss about a Q/A, meta topic, Hinduism or even off topic stuff. We can discuss about our doubts too, chats are good way to contact mods too. And in chat there is no limit to lengthy discussion, just don''t annoy others and respect there opinion too and if it turns offensive, ping a mod and leave it to them to handle.

[Here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/464/how-to-create-a-new-chat-room-thats-specific-to-hinduism-se) is a guideline to create new chat-room, but remember individual rooms didn't attract much audience and those room can be freeze and deleted automatically for inactivity. Only create them when they are needed, else no need to brag if they get freeze or deleted, mod can unfreeze and undelete but it will be temporary and activity is need to keep a chat-room alive.