# What is the Official policy for comments being moved to chat for this site?

Tags: discussion, moderators, comments, chat

Usually I flag those answers, under which the comments are not directly discussing the context of the Qn. Either it's only a less relevant part of answer or deviated or a debate. For example, I had flagged [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19310/1049) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10767/1049) answers' comment section to be converted to chat. Or flagging [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19700/what-do-lord-vishnu-and-lord-shiva-do-after-1-kalpa-when-brahmadev-goes-to-sleep#comment56765_19839) comment onwards, which don't relate to the Qn. But they were declined.
On other side, similar flags have been accepted in past. This creates confusion on when to flag & when not to.

**What is the right policy for converting comments to chat?**

All are welcomed to give their feedback on what should be the right approach.

---

**Why this Qn**
Due to nature of this site being philosophical & religious, there are less facts and more opinions; i.e. 1 scripture saying something, other saying opposite. A same scripture being interpreted differently from different Guru-s or users. So, comments would be more often about "correcting" each other rather than "clarifying". Therefore this specific policy for Hinduism.SE, being subjective cannot be derived from main SO which is black & white.

Another related post: [Guidelines for when to use "Chat" instead of "Comment"](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/485/1049)

Comment: Comments under answer can't be deleted if they are relevant to answer (though they are not related to question). If comments go offtopic, it's better to move conversation to chat.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, that's my Qn exactly. When do we move the comments to chat? This post doesn't discuss on deletion of chat at all. For example, just now I flagged [this comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19700/what-do-lord-vishnu-and-lord-shiva-do-after-1-kalpa-when-brahmadev-goes-to-sleep#comment56765_19839), which is not related to Qn of "Vishnu & Shiva" in anyways. It's rather asking my own belief system of "Yuga theory". I wished that all those irrelevant comments to be moved to chat. But the flag was rejected.

Comment: But that comment is related to your answer. How it is irrelevant to answer?

Comment: @TheDestroyer, "yuga theory" is a part of my answer, which clarifies the foundation of Qn which is on diff premises than what I am going to refer. Even without that clarification also, my answer is still eligible on its own. Now the linked comment discusses, "what is iammilind's stand on yuga theory". Which I replied. The further comments discusses that why my/others' stand is wrong on believing yogi like "Yukteswara Giri". How the Yuga theory what that user believes is right & other info on Kalki. Now how does that relates to the premises of Qn which is purely on what "Vishnu & Shiva" do?

Comment: @TheDestroyer, interestingly, above 2 comments (yours & mine) are also not relevant to the main Qn as we are debating a very small part of the Qn. :-) Better to move to chat. But I will not flag now.

Comment: Comments deviated from Yukteswar comments of Ram. But above two comments (of you and Ram ) are relevant to what you mentioned in answer. We also should see whether comments are relevant to answer (he asks some clarification which is still is relevant to above post, i.e answer).