# Comment flags should be cleared before moving them into chat

Tags: discussion, moderators, comments

Even though we know comments are not for extended discussion, comments under the question or answer goes on to become a discussion. There have been a several chat rooms which are imported from comments. When such discussions happen, few users are crossing the line and posting unfriendly and rude comments.

When there are many comments under a post (generally around 20 and keep coming), moderators are moving to chat directly without checking the comments if they are unfriendly or rude. I have flagged some comments as rude and a few as unfriendly and no longer needed. This has happened for me multiple times (A couple of them are still present in chat transcript).Such flags will be marked helpful but the comments will be changed to chat messages.

There is not much of a problem when the comments are flagged as "It's No longer needed" but it is a problem the comments are rude and unfriendly. Moving them to chat without deleting causes harmful content to stay for a long time. We don't want such content to stay for long. It creates further hot environment in chat server with flags and more discussions between user and user.

So, moderators should delete unfriendly and rude comments before moving whole conversation to chat rooms.

Related faq :

[Guidelines for when to use "Chat" instead of "Comment"](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/485/5212)

[What is the Official policy for comments being moved to chat for this site?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/906/5212)

<sup>Not giving examples because they are rude or unfriendly. Som ewere targeting a community or a region.</sup>

Comment: This is a discussion post and should not be closed as unclear what you are asking because similar posts are present on our meta as well as other meta sites including [Meta.se]. A discussion can be a question which educates users and community about policies and guidelines. I am providing a discussion which takes topic further by the input from users.

Comment: Better to give an example in question. Actually whenever there happens many comments underneath any post, [community user](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) automatically flags and suggest to move the conversation to chat. Anyway, will consider to delete such comments in chat.

Comment: They are rude and unfriendly comments. That is why I didn't link them in chat. It would look like pointing out a user. Some of such messages are deleted later after flagging and some are not. One of the examples occurred today. That triggered the post. Deleting them in comment section and moving them to chat looks better to me.

Comment: Why the downvote?